Kernel BUG at fs/inode.c:613 during installation of Debian 12.5.0
I used the Debian 12.5.0 ISO DVD image from the official website and wrote it to a USB flash drive via Rufus. During the "Load installer components from installation media" process got stuck, and by switching to the command line via CTRL+ALT+Fn, I could look at the Log and found that it triggered a Kernel Bug, is there any relevant clues?
Edited: I've tried many times and the problem occurs at different steps of the installation, but the error remains the same and 95% of the time it occurs at the "Load installer components from installation media" step.
There are two paragraphs in the Log, the first of which is:
[   20.009517] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 876 at mm/shmem.c:1193 shmem_evict_inode+0x26e/0x2b0
[   20.009521] Modules linked in: storage_ssd_mod intel_spi_cr_platform fat isofs hid_generic usbhid hid ...
[   20.009523] CPU: 0 PID: 876 Comm: kworker/u8:1 Not tainted 6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.76-1
[   20.009524] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. System Product Name/Pro WS W680-ACE IPMI, BIOS 3501 04/19/2024
[   20.009525] RIP: 0010:shmem_evict_inode+0x26e/0x2b0

The second is:
[ 20.009567] kernel BUG at fs/inode.c:613!
[ 20.009568] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[ 20.009569] CPU: 0 PID: 876 Comm: debconf Tainted: G W 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.76-1
[ 20.009571] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. System Product Name/Pro WS W680-ACE IPMI, BIOS 3501 04/12/2024
[ 20.009572] RIP: 0010:clear_inode+0x7z/0x80

See image for details:




@ArtemS.Tashkinov not a memory issue with this symptomatic. Memory corruption will lead to random things failing, not some specific dentry handling in the kernel, reproducibly.

This seems to be this file system bug; there's similar bugs in the past that got fixed already (it seems to have appeared in kernel 5.17). Chances are, it won't occur with a more modern kernel. Would you be willing to try with a more modern kernel to narrow down the problem, Redstone1024?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, this problem always occurs, the memtest86+ did not report an error in the previous 24h test. I am now trying to update the BIOS.

@MarcusMüller Your advice is good, but how do I use a newer kernel version? Isn't the Debian 12.5.0 kernel new enough?

@Redstone1024 as said, it seems it still triggers the bug on your debian kernel (6.1.0) version (or you have a new bug that people don't know about yet). You can try with a newer (6.8.5) kernel using a different Linux distro's installer; if that works, you can try to modify debian's installer (or use the testing installer, but, hm, I don't know whether you want to try debian testing, rather than a released debian version).

@ArtemS.Tashkinov huh? The shmem error hints at a page data handling error, not at a memory error.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov I updated the BIOS and retried and the problem remains the same.

Google has a ton of info on "asm_exc_invalid_op" which exists in both kernel crashes. Unfortunately it was discussed in 2023 and was seemingly solved for everyone. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=287226

@ArtemS.Tashkinov completely differnent code path than the backtrace in OP's question. This is really almost certainly the F2FS kernel bug I've already mentioned.

I don't see anything pertaining to F2FS in the above kernel oopses, nor the OP is seemingly using this filesystem in any capacity. And Rufus is unlikely to be able to format media is this format.
